# Gradle: How do I run my LIquibase changesets as part of my normal build process?

Tags: gradle, build, liquibase, changeset

I'm using Gradle 2.7 with the Gradle Liquibase plugin v 1.1.1.  How do I run my changeSets as part of doing my normal build using

```
gradle build
```

?  I currently have this in my build.gradle file ...

```
liquibase {
  activities {
    main {
        File propsFile = new File("${project.rootDir}/src/main/resources/liquibase.properties")
      Properties properties = new Properties()
      properties.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
      changeLogFile 'src/main/resources/db.changelog-1.0.xmlll'
      url '${url}'
      username '${username}'
      password '${password}'
    }
    runList = main
  }
}
```

However when I run the above command ("gradle build"), the above is not run.  I know its not run because the username/password are incorrect and I have no change log file ending in ".xmlll".  WHat else do I need to add to assure that hte plugin always attempts to execute the changeset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a task dependency from build to update.

```
build.dependsOn update
```

To get task to run before your tests (assuming you didn't define a new one), you can do

```
test.dependsOn update
```

Ref:

- [Gradle task docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks)

Comment: How do I get the task to run before tests are run?

Answer (score 0):

You can define this in your gradle build file

```
apply plugin: 'liquibase'
dependencies {
  classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.2.0'
}
liquibase {
  activities {
     main {
  changeLogFile 'changelog.xml'
  url 'jdbc:h2:db/liquibase_workshop;FILE_LOCK=NO'
  username 'sa'
  password ''
      }
 }
```

And then run this command
**gradle update**